# ServiceStack v4 : Configuring ELMAH with NLOG?

Tags: servicestack, elmah

Hi am using ServiceStack V4 . Here i tried to configure Elmah with NLog using the below statement in the AppHost construtor.

```
LogManager.LogFactory = new ElmahLogFactory(new NLogFactory(), new HttpApplication());
```

Configured Elmah to log exceptions to XML files(In web.config file).

Whenever i get an exception in the service i can see the exception in the log file(As configured for NLog) but not in XML files(For elmah).

But if i add the below statements i can see the exception logged to XML files(As configured for elmah).

```
ServiceExceptionHandlers.Add((httpReq, request, exception) =>
{
     HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
     ErrorLog.GetDefault(context).Log(new Error(exception, context));
     return DtoUtils.CreateErrorResponse(request, exception);
});
```

But the below link says we no need to add ServiceExceptionHandlers

[How do we integrate elmah logging in servicestack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995774/how-do-we-integrate-elmah-logging-in-servicestack/17259095#17259095)

Can anyone please help me out in explaining where i am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This section on [configuring Elmah](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Logging#elmah) and the [Logging.Elmah UseCase](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/tree/master/Logging.Elmah) for a working example of ServiceStack and Elmah configured together.

The `ElmahLogFactory` should be configured in your `Global.asax` before initializing the ServiceStack AppHost, e.g:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var debugMessagesLog = new ConsoleLogFactory();
        LogManager.LogFactory = new ElmahLogFactory(debugMessagesLog, this);
        new AppHost().Init();
    }
}
```

The constructor accepts an alternate logger to use for your Debug/Info messages as well as the instance of the `HttpApplication` you wish to log to which on AppStartUp is the `Global` instance itself, that is accessible at runtime at `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance`.

Comment: Perfect! It Works. Thank You mythz. The mistake I did is passing new HttpApplication object instead of present application object when configuring Elmah

Comment: As ElmahLogFactory constructor only allows httpapplication object, how can we do the same for console application.